# Looping through a multidimensional array

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm using the following code to loop through a multidimensional array and find users that went to a certain university, in this case UCF.

```
$friends = $fqlResult;
$friends_BA = array();

foreach ($friends as $friend) {
$isBA = false;
if (is_array($friend['education'])) {
    foreach ($friend['education'] as $school) {
        if (isset($school)) {
            foreach ($school['school'] as $name) {
                if (strpos(strtolower($name['name']), 'University of Central Florida') !== false) {
                    $friends_BA[] = $friend['name'];
                    continue 3; // skip to the next friend
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}

d($friends_BA);
```

The multidimensional array looks like this. It's a list of friends from the Facebook Graph API:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => PERSON
        [education] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => PERSON
        [education] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 108087985890571
                                [name] => St. Andrew's School
                            )

                        [year] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 138383069535219
                                [name] => 2005
                            )

                        [type] => High School
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 20697868961
                                [name] => Boston University
                            )

                        [concentration] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 108654845832522
                                        [name] => Business Administration
                                    )

                            )

                        [type] => College
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 108289315859633
                                [name] => University of Miami
                            )

                        [year] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 138879996141011
                                [name] => 2013
                            )

                        [type] => Graduate School
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => PERSON
        [education] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 115444241803885
                                [name] => Saint Andrews High School
                            )

                        [year] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 137616982934053
                                [name] => 2006
                            )

                        [type] => High School
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 112033702149888
                                [name] => Boca Raton High
                            )

                        [year] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 137616982934053
                                [name] => 2006
                            )

                        [type] => High School
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 108087985890571
                                [name] => St. Andrew's School
                            )

                        [type] => High School
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 107573562605861
                                [name] => Duke University
                            )

                        [concentration] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 104045469631213
                                        [name] => Political science
                                    )

                            )

                        [type] => College
                    )

            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => PERSON
        [education] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => PERSON
        [education] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 106039752760627
                                [name] => Berwick Academy
                            )

                        [year] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 137616982934053
                                [name] => 2006
                            )

                        [type] => High School
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 108087985890571
                                [name] => St. Andrew's School
                            )

                        [type] => High School
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 105690226130720
                                [name] => Northeastern University
                            )

                        [concentration] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 108654845832522
                                        [name] => Business Administration
                                    )

                            )

                        [type] => College
                        [classes] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 189873264368867
                                        [name] => 2011
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

I've run a similar program to find user's majoring in certain subjects that did work, but for some reason the code above doesn't work. Here's the one that is working:

```
$friends = $fqlResult;
$friends_BA = array();

foreach ($friends as $friend) {
$isBA = false;
if (is_array($friend['education'])) {
    foreach ($friend['education'] as $school) {
        if (isset($school['concentration'])) {
            foreach ($school['concentration'] as $concentration) {
                if (strpos(strtolower($concentration['name']), 'business') !== false) {
                    $friends_BA[] = $friend['name'];
                    continue 3; // skip to the next friend
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}

d($friends_BA);
```

As always, any help would be sincerely appreciated. Happy Holidays!

**UPDATE**

Anyone want to take a stab at this one?

```
 $friends = $fqlResult;
        $friends_BA = array();
        foreach ($friends as $friend) {
        $isBA = false;
           if (is_array($friend['current_location'])) {
              foreach ($friend['current_location'] as $location) {
                 if (isset($location)) {
                    foreach ($location['city'] as $city) {
                       $lowerName = strtolower($city);
                       if (strpos($lowerName, 'orlando') !== false || strpos($lowerName, 'gainesville') !== false) {
                       $friends_BA[] = $friend['name'];
                       continue 3; // skip to the next friend
                       }
                     }
                   }
                }
             }
          }

        d($friends_BA);
```

The array looks like this:

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => PERSONS NAME
        [current_location] => Array
            (
                [city] => New York
                [state] => New York
                [country] => United States
                [zip] => 
                [id] => 108424279189115
                [name] => New York, New York
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => PERSONS NAME
        [current_location] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => PERSONS NAME
        [current_location] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => PERSONS NAME
        [current_location] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => PERSONS NAME
        [current_location] => Array
            (
                [city] => San Jose
                [state] => California
                [country] => United States
                [zip] => 
                [id] => 111948542155151
                [name] => San Jose, California
            )

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => PERSONS NAME
        [current_location] => Array
            (
                [city] => Boston
                [state] => Massachusetts
                [country] => United States
                [zip] => 
                [id] => 106003956105810
                [name] => Boston, Massachusetts
            )

    )
```

Been playing around with it for an hour but can't seem to make it work. I'm getting invalid arguments on the second foreach statement.

Comment: Tested the code, exactly as is with the array structure and 3 entries. It returned the expected results. Are you sure you are working the most current version? Are you sure your `d` function is acting appropriately?

Comment: You're referring to the first one right? The one that looks for a UCF student?

Comment: lol whoops :) My apologies, let me look at the top one now. See answer below for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is case SensiTivity. You use `strtolower` on a string to check the university, however, the university string you posted has mixed case. Change it to this line and it should work:

```
if (strpos(strtolower($name['name']), 'university of central florida') !== false) {
```

If you want the cases to match, remove the `strtolower`, add the uppercase letters back in and it should match case as well.

**UPDATE**

The second part of the problem is `$name['name']` should be just `$name`. Since you are accessing the school array directly, it is looping through that portion.

```
if (strpos(strtolower($name), 'university of central florida') !== false) {
```

That should do it. So basically the foreach was looping over the school array, so the name comes out as a string value instead of being apart of the array.

**UPDATE 2**

```
$lowerName = strtolower($name);
if (strpos($lowerName, 'university of central florida') !== false
        || strpos($lowerName, 'ucf') !== false) {
```

Comment: Still nothing. Just an empty array.

Comment: How could I check university of central florida or ucf? in that statement?

Comment: Let me know if you see anything wrong with the location one. I've been trying to get it work for an hour or so to no avail. It's updated above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go over whole array with these 2 functions together.

They are totally dynamic and will go over **multidimensional array** of any complexity.

I'm using it to echo all dimensions as 1, you might you use it to check key=>value pairs and check if it is the one you are looking for.

```
function workwitharrays($v) {
if (is_array($v)) {
foreach ($v as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        workwitharrays($value);
    } elseif (!is_array($value)) {
        echo "<tr><td>{$key}</td><td>{$value}</td></tr>";
    }
}
}
}

function array_get_key_val($firstarray) {
if (is_array($firstarray)) {
foreach ($firstarray as $k => $v) {
    if (is_array($v)) {
        workwitharrays($v);
    } elseif (!is_array($v)) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$k}</td><td>{$v}</td></tr>";
    }
}
}
}

echo "<table><tbody>";
array_get_key_val($ArrayMultidim);
echo "</tbody></table";
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you elaborate on what you mean by "didn't work"? If your test data is correct then nothing should be added to your $friends_BA[] array because none of those people attended the 'University of Central Florida'.

Are you getting an error? You might want to strip the apostrophes out of your values. St. Andrew's may cause a problem when the if statment tries to do this

```
If('St. Andrew's' == 'University of Central Florida')
```

This should cause an error.

Comment: I think you need to read up more about how an quote inside of a variable does not need to be escape to test it against another value. If St. Andrew's is coming from the array and he is not manually writing it, it will parse just fine. If he is manually writing it, well you would change the single quotes around it to double quotes and it will work fine as well or simply escape it. But that is not the issue here.

Comment: I mean it just returned an empty array. Getting rid of the apostrophe just brings an error re: strings.

Comment: Thanks for the info Brad. I'm aware of most of that. At the time I was stabbing in the dark because I wasn't sure what he meant by "doesn't work". He clarified by saying it just returns an empty array. Matt, are you certain there is a value inside the array that is equal to "University of Central Florida"? Your test case does not have such value. On that test case, an empty array should be returned, correct? In other words, I think it is working correctly for that test case.

Comment: I'm using my own FB account so I didn't want to copy all of my friend list, just give everyone an idea of the structure.